# Extracting specific xml tag value using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have XML data which looks like this:

```
    <root>
      <results preview='0'>
        <meta>
          <fieldOrder>
        <field>title</field>
        <field>search</field>
          </fieldOrder>
        </meta>
        <messages>
          <msg type="DEBUG">msg1</msg>
          <msg type="DEBUG">msg2</msg>
        </messages>
        <result offset='0'>
          <field k='title'>
        <value>
          <text>text1</text>
        </value>
          </field>
          <field k='search'>
        <value>
          <text>text2</text>
        </value>
          </field>
        </result>
      </results>
    </root>
```

I want to extract the tag value `text2` from the tag `k='search'>value>text`.

In my code, I am trying the following:

```
for atype in root.findall(".//text"):
    print(atype.text)
```

This gives me both `text1` and `text2` as output. Out of these I need only `text2`. I could handle this in my program to have an `if` statement to filter only the `text2` value, but I want to find a more robust way to do this in `findall()`.

I have tried this code instead to specifically extract only `text2` as output.

```
for atype in root.findall(".//field[@k='search']//text"):
    print(atype.text)
```

But this gives me an error -

```
File "command_curl", line 49, in <module>
for atype in root.findall(".//field[@k='search']//text"):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 355, in findall
return ElementPath.findall(self, path)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 198, in findall
return _compile(path).findall(element)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 176, in _compile
p = Path(path)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
"expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)
```

What should I change to get only `text2` as my output?

Comment: Worked fine in Python 2.7 : https://eval.in/526370

Comment: I tried your `findall` and it worked for me for both elementtree and lxml. Do you have a really old elementtree?

Comment: Thank you har07 and tdelaney . I had an old version of elementtree as you suggested . After pointing  to a newer version of python the code is working fine now .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you har07 and tdelaney . I had an old version of elementtree as you mentioned . After pointing to a newer version of python the code is working fine now .

Answer (score 0):

You can extract text from tag, using below example

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for tags in root.findall(".//text"):
    print(tags.text)
```